# Making a view transition without animation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I have an angular app and it uses animation for view transitions but there is one place in my code where I change the view using the $location service ($location.path()) and in that specific case I want to make that transition with no animation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$animation.enabled()` to globally enable and disable animation. [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate.%24animate)

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I was looking for. The only problem is that $location.path() is not synchronous, so I'd have to listen for a successful route navigation to then set $animate.enabled() back to true. Thought maybe there was a one-liner for a navigation animation off but thanks anyway.